# Complicated semaphore for scripts

Tags: linux

I have 2 types of scripts:

- jobA: Many instances can run at the same time
- jobB: Only one instance can run at the same time

a jobB script can only run when no jobA or jobB are running

a jobA script can run if there are other jobA, but no jobB running

---

I had the idea to use some kind of semaphore for this.
I think I have to save the available slots somewhere, and lock until one slot is free, like this

```
take 1
jobA
release 1
```

jobB would have to wait until all slots are free, and take them all

```
take all
jobB
release all
```

I tried using `sem` from GNU Parallel, but I cannot find a way to ensure that `jobA` does not run when `jobB` is running.

```
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 1 finished';   echo jobA 1 running
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 2 finished';   echo jobA 2 running
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 3 finished';   echo jobA 3 running
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 4 finished';   echo jobA 4 running
sem -j 1 'sleep 4;echo jobB a finished';   echo jobB 1 running
sem -j 1 'sleep 4;echo jobB b finished';   echo jobB 2 running
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 5 finished';   echo jobA 5 running
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 6 finished';   echo jobA 6 running
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 7 finished';   echo jobA 7 running
sem -j 3 'sleep 4;echo jobA 8 finished';   echo jobA 8 running
sem -j 1 'sleep 4;echo jobB c finished';   echo jobB 3 running
sem --wait; echo sem --wait done
```

```
jobA 1 running
jobA 2 running
jobA 3 running
jobA 1 finished
jobA 4 running
jobA 2 finished
jobA 3 finished
jobA 4 finished
jobB 1 running <--- this jobB waits for the jobAs above to complete
jobB 1 finished
jobB 2 running
jobA 5 running <---
jobA 6 running <--- these 2 started running but jobB 2 was still running
jobB 2 finished
jobA 5 finished
jobA 6 finished
jobA 7 running
jobA 8 running
jobA 7 finished
jobA 8 finished
jobB 3 running
jobB 3 finished
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using the `flock` program that's part of the `util-linux` package (which means it should be available pretty much everywhere).

Job A will take a read (shared) lock on a lockfile, and job B will take an exclusive lock on the same file. That means:

- Any number of job A can run in parallel as long as job B doesn't hold the exclusive lock
- Job B can only run if no other job A or job B is holding a shared or exclusive lock on the lock file

A simple implementation might look like the following...

In `jobA.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

flock -s /tmp/job.lock bash <<'EOF'
echo "Start is job A"
sleep $((RANDOM % 20))
echo "End job A"
EOF
```

In `jobB.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

flock -x /tmp/job.lock bash <<'EOF'
echo "Start is job B"
sleep $((RANDOM % 20))
echo "End job B"
EOF
```

Play around with those and see if they accomplish your goal.